# How to override defaults in Android.bp

Tags: android-source, android.mk

For example,in Android  9.0.0_r30 source,there are two Android.bp files:

```
art\build\Android.bp
art\tools\hiddenapi\Android.bp
```

in art\build\Android.bp,there is "art_defaults",under which there are cflags:

```
            "-msse4.2",
            "-mpopcnt",
```

and in art\tools\hiddenapi\Android.bp,there is

```
"defaults: ["art_defaults"]"
```

,so it reference the "art_defaults" in art\build\Android.bp ,as a result it have the above cflags.

The question is,is there any easy way to disable the above cflags only in the module hiddenapi under art?(i.e. not to write complex Go scripts)

And the more general question is how to override any configuration in Android.bp.

As I know there are very few documents about Android.bp,the only document I know is https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/

Comment: Were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: No, it seems that the only people who know this is in Google and they don't answer questions daily here.